# Problem to get list of statistics using curl commend - REST API

Tags: python, rest, curl, post, get

I would like to get list of statistic from this page by curl:
https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics

i trying used command:

*curl "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" --compressed -H "Referer: https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "TE: Trailers" --data "world=Kenora&Submit.x=78&Submit.y=14"*

But i getting response from server: You don't have permission to access

Could you please help me, what i doing wrong ?
Mayby is easier way to get this list ( writing python code).

I write some code in python, but still does not get a list :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

server = "Kenora"
yourparams={'world':server}

url = 'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics'
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) > AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=agent,params=yourparams)

print (BS(page.content, 'lxml'))
```

Comment: show the exact the response you're getting. `You don't have permission to access` ? what more? for the record, this exact command works fine here: `curl 'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=killstatistics' --data 'world=Kenora&Submit.x=68&Submit.y=6'`

Comment: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;tibia&#46;com&#47;community&#47;&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;e7941160&#46;1540748314&#46;12342271
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: most likely explanation: your system's default DNS server is a lying piece of shit. try using GoogleDNS (8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4) instead. other possible explanations: you're using a MITM proxy or VPN blocking access to tibia.com, or your IP is actually blacklisted from tibia.com

Comment: this will bypass the DNS, does this work?  `curl 'https://104.120.243.149/community/?subtopic=killstatistics' --data 'world=Kenora&Submit.x=68&Submit.y=6' --insecure -H "Host: www.tibia.com"`